# How can I force users to enable full screen while taking the test using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

I am developing  a quiz app for my academic project. whenever a user attempts a quiz, he must enable fullscreen mode before taking the test. If he do so then only he can attempt the quiz. If he disable the full screen mode by pressing esc key then a warning message should be shown and he cannot attempt the quiz until he reenables full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript Full-Screen API

here's how you can use it

```js
// DOM element which needs to enter fullscreen mode
var element = document.querySelector("#container");

element.requestFullscreen()
  .then(function() {
    // element has entered fullscreen mode successfully
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // element could not enter fullscreen mode
    // error message
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```